# make excel to understand encoded xml format

Tags: xml, excel, encoding, decoding

To get the  physical image path in excel file dynamically, I have to used below code.

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\","*",LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\",""))),1))&"D04523.jpg"
```

But as my excel file is xml based `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet` format, I have to encode every `"` double quotes like below.

```
=LEFT(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1),FIND(&quot;*&quot;,SUBSTITUTE(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1),&quot;\&quot;,&quot;*&quot;,LEN(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1),&quot;\&quot;,&quot;&quot;))),1))&amp;&quot;D04523.jpg&quot;
```

Everything is correct in xml file, but problem is excel file cannot decode `&quot;`.

Below is my xml file which can be opened in excel application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">  
  <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <ss:Table>
      <ss:Row>

        <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">1</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">2</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>

      </ss:Row>
      <ss:Row>        

        <!-- Error happen : An unexpected error has occured. -->
        <ss:Cell                
        ss:HRef="=LEFT(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1),FIND(&quot;*&quot;,SUBSTITUTE(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1),&quot;\&quot;,&quot;*&quot;,LEN(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,A1),&quot;\&quot;,&quot;&quot;))),1))&amp;&quot;D04523.jpg&quot;">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">View Image 1</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>  

        <!-- This can view image when user click. But I don't want to use hard coded path.-->
        <ss:Cell                
        ss:HRef="D:\05.Project\ExcelResearch\D04523.jpg">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">View Image 2</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>  

      </ss:Row>
    </ss:Table>
  </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

So my question

How can I make excel to understand encoded formula?

OR

How can I modify xml file to escape the double quote `"`?
I tried using slash but does not work.

Comment: Is it possible that your encoding for Excel in preferences is not set to 'UTF-8"?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using `ss:Formula` and not `ss:Href` ?

Here's what I got after saving a workbook with the formula you posted:

```
<Cell ss:Index="2"
ss:Formula="=LEFT(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,RC[-1]),FIND(&quot;*&quot;,SUBSTITUTE(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,RC[-1]),&quot;\&quot;,&quot;*&quot;,LEN(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,RC[-1]))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL(&quot;filename&quot;,RC[-1]),&quot;\&quot;,&quot;&quot;))),1))&amp;&quot;D04523.jpg&quot;">
<Data ss:Type="Error">#VALUE!</Data>
</Cell>
```